# Subset a data frame for specific row names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm fairly new to coding and hope I can get some help here on StackOverflow. I have a large dataframe with 16871 observations and 11 variables. I have another txt file with a list of 1118. I'd like to create a new dataset by selecting from the 16871, the exact 1118 rownames.

[image: Large Dataframe]

[image: List of 1118 genes]

The line I'm using to subset it is:

```
JustTTXGenes<-SELECTED_ALEX_BRUSEQ_JULY2018[row.names(SELECTED_ALEX_BRUSEQ_JULY2018) %in% TTXResponseGenes,]
```

But for some reason, JustTTXGenes is coming up with 0 observations and 11 variables. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you should use `SELECTED_ALEX_BRUSEQ_JULY2018$Geneid` instead of  `row.names(SELECTED_ALEX_BRUSEQ_JULY2018)`. Or with `dplyr`: `SELECTED_ALEX_BRUSEQ_JULY2018 %>% inner_join(TTXResponseGenes, by = "Geneid")`.

Comment: Thank you for your response Martin.

JustTTXGenes <- SELECTED_ALEX_BRUSEQ_JULY2018[SELECTED_ALEX_BRUSEQ_JULY2018$Geneid %in% TTXResponseGenes,]

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Is `TTXResponseGenes` a dataframe  or a `vector`?

Comment: TTXResponseGenes is a vector.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.